# make javascript variable from string

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to make a variable dynamically.
Example-

```
var a ="pres"+b;
```

where b is a variable, and then use `a` as a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be in a much confortable solution using an object to store values, and the bracket notation :

```
var store = {};

var theEnd = 'Something';

store['b'+ theEnd] = 10 ;

store['c'+ theEnd] = 20 ;
```

You can easily iterate in existing keys and values with :

```
 for (var key in store) {
     var value = store[key];
     console.log(' store has key:' + key + '  having value ' + value);
 }

 // output :  
 // store has key bSomething having value 10
 // store has key cSomething having value 20
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to use eval() to do this... but dont be eval! this is not a good style!

Comment: what about window variable? eg window[a]

Comment: why not using an object? if u have to convert it to string and back use JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a no logical;
Is normal that a and b are variables|||

You have to use  `new String("string");` and in your case

```
 var a = new String("pres")+b ;
```

but you can use simplier `var a ="pres"+b;`